# Facebook C# SDK integration in Silverlight without Asp.Net

Tags: silverlight, facebook, silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Heyho,

unfortunaly I don't own a Asp.Net host. Thats why I was searching for examples using the C# Facebook SDK without a Asp.Net implementation. One site showing it is the following: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

There is one problem with this one: I'm using a in-browser Silverlight application which is hosted in the facebook canvas. The WebBrowser-Control, which this site uses, is only available for Out-Of-Browser applications. Here is what I currently got: http://pastebin.com/DDsyNuvU

My question is if there are any possibilities to handle all this without using Asp.Net and manage it all inside Silverlight or with any method provided by Facebook in the fb canvas?